# regex in R: how to exclude strings that contain some specific numeric values (length > 1)?

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings in R:

```
mystrings <- c("S0701",   "S0702",   "S0703",   "S0704",   "S0705",   "S0706",   "S0707",   "S0708",   "S0709",   "S0710",   "S0711",   "S0712",  
       "S0713",   "S0714",   "S07_oth")
```

I want to exclude the last 3 strings using regex.
I tried:

`grep("S07[^oth|13]*$", mystrings, value = TRUE)`

But this eliminates all strings that contain 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14.
These don't work either:

```
grep("S07[^oth | (13|14))]*$", total, value = TRUE)
grep("S07[^(oth | 13 | 14)]*$", total, value = TRUE) 
grep("S07[^(oth | (13) | (14))]*$", total, value = TRUE) 
grep("S07[^oth | [1-1][3-4])*$", mystrings, value = TRUE)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I want the strings that contain "13", "14", and "oth" to be removed

Comment: Thank you! So, what's the difference between grep and grepl?

Comment: @user3245256 - see `help(grep)`

Comment: If you need to only avoid matching strings ending with those values use `grep("(?:oth|1[34])$", mystrings, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)`

Answer (score 6):

you almost had it:

```
grep("oth|1[34]", mystrings, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)

"S0701" "S0702" "S0703" "S0704" "S0705" "S0706" "S0707" "S0708" "S0709" "S0710" "S0711"
"S0712"
```

Comment: I am curious, why both of these work:  grep("oth|1[34]", mystrings, value = TRUE, invert = T) and also grep("oth|13|14", mystrings, value = TRUE, invert = T)

Comment: And why doesn't this work? grep("S07[^oth|13|14]]*$", mystrings, value = TRUE) ? I just realized - I need to keep S07 - so, need to have it as a positive statement

Comment: you can play around with different regex expressions to see what works here: https://regexr.com/